# Using assert to check it is true that a condition is False in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, boolean, pytest, assert

***EDIT:*** *the file was being created then removed elsewhere in my script so did not appear to exist in my working directory whenever I checked. I can't delete this post but shall clarify that the code below (unedited from original post) does indeed work.*

I'm using `pytest`, and am looking to use `assert` to check it is true that a certain statement is false - for example, that an item does not exist in a list. For example:

```
def test_file_created(self):

    '''Checks that a non-existing file exists in the current
    working dir after construction of a new MyClass instance.'''

    assert not 'myfile.txt' in os.listdir()    # This is the line I need help with!

    x = MyClass()                              # A class that writes a file
    x.createfile('myfile.txt')

    assert 'myfile.txt' in os.listdir()
```

The above returns an `AssertionError`, as does `assert 'myfile.txt' in os.listdir() == False`. Is this not possible, or is there some creative way around this?

Comment: If `assert not 'myfile.txt' in os.listdir()` throws, then there *is* a file named `myfile.txt` in the current directory. Did you forget to write cleanup code for your tests?

Comment: `in` and `==` are both comparison operators, so `x in y == False` is the same as `x in y and y == False`.

Comment: I've realised I made an error - my setup code was making the file, and as my cleanup code was then removing the file whenever I looked in the directory and couldn't see the file, I assumed it was a problem with my assert statement!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct. It's behaving as it should be, assuming that the file does exist in the working dir. An AssertionError is raised when the assertion is False; and the assertion passes if it's true.

That means that the AssertionError is raised BECAUSE the file exists, because the assertion that it DOESN'T exist fails.

Perhaps you want to skip creating the file if it already exists; but still pass the test?

Comment: The `not` assertion is asserting that the file doesn't exist before it's created. (Apparently the file already exists.)